# Which light C++ event/delegate (signal/slot) library should I choose?

Tags: c++, signals-slots

I know that the [question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359928/which-c-signals-slots-library-should-i-choose) and answered, but it was more than one year ago and it looks like there are new alternatives out there.

So I'm coding a game with the [SFML library](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (which I'm starting to find pretty much cool actually) and I'm looking for a light and fast event/delegate library.

After doing some research and having put aside the classical ones ([Boosts.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/signals.html), [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/)), I found "[cpp-events](http://code.google.com/p/cpp-events/)". It does not look very popular right now — since it is a very recent library — but it seems worst to be tested. I would be very interested to know if someone here tried it and can give a little feedback.

Do you have other similar (or better) options to suggest? I look rather real projects (which will be maintained) than answers on forums.

Thank you !

Comment: The other question can be updated with new answers and/or edits.

Answer (score 3):

My feeling is that http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ImpossiblyFastCppDelegate.aspx is a great implementation for games. No dynamic memory allocation, reasonable performance, simple to debug => great for games.

I have used similar delegates in the past, this implementation looks more efficient.

The one you suggested mentions thread safety, but I would not be comfortable with a delegate based interface being used between threads. That may work fine on a small project but if a team grows, so too does the potential for disaster. I would also question the performance implications of such a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/signals2/) which is the thread-safe version of Boost.Signals. I'm using it at work in a medium-sized project and I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: +1 I would use Signals2 even when thread-safety is not needed because it is also header-only.