# C++ Signals/Slot: Slot processing and best C++ Signal library?

Tags: c++, signals, signals-slots

I currently have a program which use busy pooling and a bunch of thread to monitor states of object, process data, and pass data.. This is all very hard to manage/waste cpu time. I am looking at removing thread and using signal / slot as there is none of my code which "block".

So I will signal states of my object, which is easy. What's harder is I also want to use slots to signals Data, and pass the data.

Basically: 
A->SignalIHAVEDATA(B.slot() and C.slot())
B and C might not be able to process the data. So should I keep a flag in B and C telling them they is data. Or should I just Re-signal every X ms until the data has been taken.

Also..

Lets say B accept the data. Would it make sense that Inside the B.Slot, it take handleToA->getData(); && process the data? && signalAnotherThing.

If I emit signalA and within slotA I emit a signalB would the slotB  be processed before slotA return? (If this chain is very long it might take a while before slotA return?)

Thanks for helping:)

Comment: Have you looked into the Qt framework?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359928/which-c-signals-slots-library-should-i-choose

Answer (score 4):

The best signal & slot library is of course [Boost.Signal2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/signals2.html). 
It's portable, thread-safe, template-based and header only. You'll love it.

And yes. I know you asked this one year ago, but I simply couldn't left it unanswered.