# Boost::signals2 - descruction of an object with the slot

Tags: c++, boost, signals, boost-signals, boost-signals2

Consider this:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct object_with_slot
{
void operator()()
{
   std::cout << "Slot called!" << std::endl;
   member = 50500;
}
int member;
};


int main()
{
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

object_with_slot * ptr = new object_with_slot;
sig.connect(*ptr);

delete ptr;

sig();
}
```

Output is "Slot called!" and no crash or anything. That's why I have a few questions:

1) Why there is no crash?

2) Why there is no crash even if the slot function assigns something to object which doesn't exist?

3) How can I make the signal automatically track the lifetime of its slots? I mean when the  slot is destroyed, it gets disconnected.

The question number 3 is the most important, as I need to implement observer pattern and very often lifetime of observers (slots) won't be static (for the whole time when app is running).

Comment: Please use value semantics for signals. Do not shove references into them and then delete the source of those references. There's no reason to allocate this signal object here.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas could you explain it a bit?

Comment: Just do `sig.connect(object_with_slot())`. Then there are no lifetime issues. There's a reason why `sig.connect` takes a *reference*, and not a pointer.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas but if the operator() modifies some data in the object, after destroying it may still corrupt the memory. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You're lucky. If not, you'll get a segmentation fault.

2) The memory was not overwritten in any way.

3) You could use slot::track to automatically disconnect when the tracked object gets deleted. Boost.Signals2 could track objects that are managed by boost::shared_ptr.

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct object_with_slot
{
    void operator()()
    {
       std::cout << "Slot called!" << std::endl;
       member = 50500;
    }
    int member;
};

//
int main()
{
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig_type;
    sig_type sig;

    {
        boost::shared_ptr<object_with_slot> ptr(new object_with_slot);
        sig.connect(sig_type::slot_type(*ptr).track(ptr));

        // 'object_with_slot' managed by ptr is destroyed
    }

    sig(); // 'object_with_slot' not called here.

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Added code to track objects for std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

// added specializations for std::weak_ptr and std::shared_ptr
namespace boost
{
  namespace signals2
  {
    template<typename T> struct weak_ptr_traits<std::weak_ptr<T> >
    {
      typedef std::shared_ptr<T> shared_type;
    };

    template<typename T> struct shared_ptr_traits<std::shared_ptr<T> >
    {
      typedef std::weak_ptr<T> weak_type;
    };
  }
}

struct object_with_slot
{
    void operator()()
    {
       std::cout << "Slot called!" << std::endl;
       member = 50500;
    }
    int member;
};

//
int main()
{
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig_type;
    sig_type sig;

    std::shared_ptr<object_with_slot> ptr(new object_with_slot);
    sig.connect(sig_type::slot_type(*ptr).track_foreign(ptr)); // ptr is tracked

    sig();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't knew about the track feature.

Comment: @Grigoriy Chudnov is there any way to make it work with std::shared_ptr?

Comment: @user1873947, yes it is possible if you use 'track_foreign' instead of 'track'. But, you might need to provide  boost::signals2::shared_ptr_traits & boost::signals2::weak_ptr_traits specializations

Comment: @Grigoriy Chudnov Thank you. But, I have no idea how should this specialisation look like. Is there any ready code, could you guide me a bit?

Comment: According to a more recent boost::signals2 reference, 'track_foreign' already contains [traits specializations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/slot.html#id1112530-bb) for std::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2) In fact it is an undefined behaviour. You employed the dereference operator, now connect has the value of the object_with_slot, its address is free to be assigned by memory manager to any other process. By coincidence it is still a "valid address". And ptr is free to be assigned to any other value without cause memory leak.

Try something like this and you will see that explodes everytime

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct object_with_slot
{
    object_with_slot()
    {
        member = new int(10);
    }

    ~object_with_slot()
    {
        delete member; //comment this line and everything works again
    }
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Slot called!" << std::endl;
        *member = 50500; //it was destroyed above
    }
    int *member;
};


int main()
{
    boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig;

    object_with_slot * ptr = new object_with_slot;
    sig.connect(*ptr);

    delete ptr;
    ptr = 0x0;

    sig();
}
```

3) You can put another signal on destructor of object_with_slot, then it can notify when it is called.

Comment: thank you for great answer. And I didn't think that answer for 3) is so simple, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very dangerous examples are given. Take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

struct object_with_slot
{
    object_with_slot() {
        std::cout << "ctor\n";
    }

    object_with_slot(const object_with_slot &) {
        std::cout << "cctor\n";
    }

    ~object_with_slot() {
        std::cout << "dtor\n";
    }

    void operator()()
    {
       std::cout << "Slot called!" << std::endl;
       member = 50500;
    }
    int member;
};

//
int main()
{
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> sig_type;
    sig_type sig;

    std::shared_ptr<object_with_slot> ptr(new object_with_slot);
    sig.connect(sig_type::slot_type(*ptr).track_foreign(ptr)); // ptr is tracked

    sig();

    return 0;
}
```

How do you think, what does this code out (g++ 4.8.1, libboost 1.54)?

```
ctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
cctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
cctor
dtor
cctor
dtor
dtor
dtor
cctor
dtor
Slot called!
dtor
dtor
```

I don't think, that this behaviour was expected. Because we pass copy (by value) of `*ptr` (instance of `object_with_slot`) to the `connect` method. It might be solved, for example, by reference wrappers:

```
sig.connect(sig_type::slot_type(boost::ref(*ptr)).track_foreign(ptr)); // ptr is tracked
```

Be careful with templates and types.