# passing function objects pointers to functions accepting a pointer to a std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function

I would like to pass functors of different types but identical signatures to a method. Hence I concluded that std::function should be used. But as this method should also store a reference to the function object I want to pass a shared_ptr instead (for lifetime management). The code below works for class B (b.run(...)) but fails to compile for class A (a.run(...) breaks).
What is the reason for this conversion problem when a pointer is passed instead of the function object itself and how can I circumvent it?

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class MyFunctor
{
public:
    void operator()(const float &f)
    {}
};

template<class FunSig>
class A
{
public:
    void run(std::shared_ptr<std::function<FunSig> > f_ptr)
    {
         // store f_ptr in a vector
    }
};

template<class FunSig>
class B
{
public:
    void run(std::function<FunSig> f)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    MyFunctor mf1;
    std::shared_ptr<MyFunctor> mf2_ptr(new MyFunctor);

    A<void (const float &)> a;
    B<void (const float &)> b;

    a.run(mf2_ptr);        // this breaks!
    b.run(mf1);            // this works
}
```

The compiler error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A<void(const float&)>::run(std::shared_ptr<MyFunctor>&)’
note: candidate is:
note: void A<FunSig>::run(std::shared_ptr<std::function<FunSig> >) [with FunSig = void(const float&)]
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::shared_ptr<MyFunctor>’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(const float&)> >
```

Now I discovered that a.run(...) compiles if MyFunctor inherits from std::function:

```
class MyFunctor : public std::function<void (const float &)>
```

Why does this work now? I would be nicer if no code changes were necessary in the functors.

Comment: The problem here is a typecast. MyFunctor* is a pointer to the MyFunctor struct, std::function<void (const float&)>* is a pointer to a std::function object: your code compiles when MyFunctor inherits from std::function because it is now a subclass of std::function and thus can be cast implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking why this doesn't work:

```
struct Integer
{
    int value;
};

std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(1));

std::shared_ptr<Integer> p2 = p;
```

It doesn't work because they're not the same type.  Just because you can store a `MyFunctor` in a `std::function<void(const float&)>` doesn't mean that a pointer to one is convertible to a pointer to the other.

You want:

```
auto mf2_ptr = std::make_shared<std::function<void (const float &)>>( MyFunctor() );
a.run(mf2_ptr);
```

> Now I discovered that a.run(...) compiles if MyFunctor inherits from std::function:

It compiles because now you can convert `shared_ptr<MyFunctor>` to `shared_ptr<function<void(const float&)>>`, but it won't work correctly.  `std::function::operator()()` is not virtual, so if you call the function it will call the base class' `operator()`, but the base class doesn't point to anything and will throw `std::bad_cast`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is actually very obvious after a good night's sleep... So either I pass a pointer to a std:function or all functors inherit from a common class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understanding why you want a reference to the std::function object.  Unless you really want shared reference semantics (for example, the ability for someone else to modify what function object is being used), just store a std::function object directly.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882867/boostsignals2-descruction-of-an-object-with-the-slot). I want something similar to track the lifetime of the functor.