# C++ return value to caller from deep stack without `throw`

Tags: c++, optimization, throw

I am using the visitor pattern to traverse a tree made up of many different types of nodes, something like this:

```
class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(TypeA &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeB &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeC &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeD &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeE &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeF &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeG &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(TypeH &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Returner &) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Caller &) = 0;
};
```

Each of the visitor functions can potentially call any other visitor function since the Types are arranged in a tree. For example, `visit(TypeA &)` might be implemented as follows:

```
void ClassWhichInheritedVisitor::visit(TypeA & a){
    a.bChild->accept(*this);
    a.fChild->accept(*this);
    a.callerChild->accept(*this);
}
```

Now, I have a value generated in `visit(Returner &)` which I would like to pass back to the most recent call of `visit(Caller &)`. My current solution is to `throw` the value from `visit(Returner &)` and catch it in `visit(Caller &)`, however, I have read that exception handling can be very slow.

One solution might be to store the return value in some member variable and check for a value after each call to `accept(*this)` for any child, however, this makes the code bloated and difficult to read. Maybe this could be eased with a preprocessor macro?

```
#define visit(target);      \
    target->accept(*this);  \
    if (returnValuePresent) \
        return;
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to return this value without checking for a value after each call to `accept(*this)`, considering that there might easily be 5/6 function calls between the call to `visit(Caller &)` and `visit(Returner &)`?

Comment: Are you looking for a signal/slot mechanism?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359928/which-c-signals-slots-library-should-i-choose

Comment: @Yipi No, when a value is generated by `visit(Returner &)` I would like to prevent any of the previous calls from continuing execution and pass control directly back to `visit(Caller &)`. This is different from a signal/slot which passes a value to a listener and invokes some behaviour.

Comment: A common idiom is to have `visit(...)` return a bool: `true` means continue as-is and `false` means stop the traversal immediately.  That could be extended to include a result of some type if required.

Comment: @G.M. I would like the `Visitor` to return `void` for a couple of reasons. Firstly from a performance standpoint, returning some value (a `std::string` in this case) will definitely increase the size of the stack frame and will likely call a copy for every return, even though only 2 functions are actually concerned with its return value. Besides, I mentioned that checking `if(!a.bChild->accept(*this)) return false;`, for every `accept` call is undesirable. I also have other visitor classes which don't need a return value and ideally I don't split them up into `VoidVisitor` and `StringVisitor`.